# Access element's property from dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using a `dom-repeat` template in my element, and I want to use the property `typeElement` of that element (`<custom-element>`) in a new element (`<media-element>`) from within `dom-repeat`:

```html
<dom-module id="custom-element">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{array}}" as="file">
      <media-element some-prop="{{typeElement}}" file="{{file}}"></media-element>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-element',
      properties: {
        typeElement: Number,
        array: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() { return[]; }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please make it more clear what you want. What is "a property" and "that element"?

Comment: What is the problem? Does it not work?

Comment: Done, it's more clear, and no it's not wotking, when i debug the <media-element> the someProp propertie is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured myself, the problem isn't here. The problem was on the child element (`<media-element>`). So i'll post a new question te resolve the problem:

how do the properties of an element been initialized before the element creation? Or, how to trigger the dom-if recalling my condition function after propertie change/init?

My code:

```
<dom-module id="media-element">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[isType(0)]]">
      ....
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'media-element',
      properties: {
        myType: {
          type: Number,
          value: 0
        }
      },
      isType: function(t){return (this.myType===t);}
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

UPDATE: I sent my question and receive a goode answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515593/how-do-i-get-the-dom-if-to-re-evaluate-its-if-condition)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "use the property", so I'm making assumptions below.

Assuming you want to set `<media-element>.someProp` to the value of `<custom-element>.typeElement`, then your data binding is correct. Whenever the value of `typeElement` changes, `someProp` will be set to the same value. You could access the value in a method of `<media-element>` with `this.someProp`. Example:

```
<dom-module id="media-element">
  <template>...</template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'media-element',
      properties: {
        someProp: Number
      },
      foo: function() {
        console.log(this.someProp);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Assuming you also want the changes to `<media-element>.someProp` to update `<custom-element>.typeElement`, then you'd need to set `notify: true` on the property declaration of `someProp`:

```
// media-element
properties: {
  someProp: {
    type: Number,
    notify: true  // <-- only needed for upward notifications (two-way data binding and observers)
  }
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'custom-element',
    properties: {
      typeElement: {
        type: Number,
        value: 100,
        observer: '_typeElementChanged'
      }
    },
    _typeElementChanged: function(typeElement) {
      console.log('new typeElement', typeElement);
    }
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'media-element',
    properties: {
      someProp: {
        type: Number,
        notify: true
      }
    },
    _logSomeProp: function() {
      console.log('someProp', this.someProp);
    },
    _incrementSomeProp: function() {
      this.someProp++;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <custom-element></custom-element>

  <dom-module id="custom-element">
    <template>
      <media-element some-prop="{{typeElement}}"></media-element>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="media-element">
    <template>
      <button on-tap="_logSomeProp">Log someProp</button>
      <button on-tap="_incrementSomeProp">Incremeent someProp</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/Mpwram?editors=1011)

I recommend reading [*Polymer Data Binding*](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding).

Answer (score 0):

because settings property like:
`typeElement: Number` won't work. You have to define it like you defined `array` property. so:

```
typeElement: {
 type: Number,
 value: Number,
}
```

i don't know what value you want to have. After this it should work

Comment: It does work - [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties)